# Sizeof struct is not clear even with padding

Tags: c++

In the following struct, I feel the size should be 20, but it's coming out to be 24.

```
class X {
  unsigned int a;
  unsigned int b;
  double       c;
  unsigned int d;
};
```

Why can't the compiler arrange `d` from 16-20 bytes ?

Comment: what is your equation ?

Comment: you need to specify your environment

Answer (score 6):

This is so that `c` remains aligned on an 8-byte boundary in an array of `X`.

```
X x[2];

X[0]:
0-3    unsigned int a
4-7    unsigned int b
8-15   double       c
16-19  unsigned int d
20-23  [PAD]
X[1]:
24-27    unsigned int a
28-31    unsigned int b
32-39   double       c
40-43  unsigned int d
44-47  [PAD]
```

So, you can see that you need 4 bytes of pad between the array elements. This is captured by adding 4-bytes at the end of the object. If the second array element started at position `20`, then you find that `x[1].c` was not 8 byte aligned.

So, finally, `d` does start at byte 16 as you expect, but the end of `d` is  not the end of the object.

Comment: ok.. thanks is there any way I can make the size 20 for the same struct?

Comment: No, if you mean "can I reorder to take less storage", I don't see how.

Comment: Actually in the original problem I had, 'c' was a void* (64-bit arch).. and I can break c into two 'ints' and later reconstruct c. breaking c into two ints will make the size 20.

Comment: If you don't really need 32-bits for `a,c,d`, you might squeeze them into 8 bytes using bit fields. e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: @user3651312: There is no portable way to "make the size 20". But your platform and compiler may (or may not) have a machine dependent way to request "packed" structures. For example, GCC has `__attribute__((packed))`. If you update your question to specify your platform and compiler, someone may have a better suggestion for you.

Comment: Is there any side effect of forcing the 4-byte alignment.. that resulted in the size being 20 of the same struct.

Comment: @user3651312: Pretty much the same as your idea of breaking the 8 byte variale in two 4 byte variables: all accesses are split in two, which slows down your code. Letting the compiler do it will give you slow & correct code. You can't make it faster but you can make it buggier.

Answer (score 1):

In POD structs like this, the address of the `struct` is the address of its first element. The size is the distance in memory between successive elements of an array of type `X[]`. For the `double` to be aligned in the second element of a hypothetical array, the first `int` and the entire `struct` must be aligned to the same strictness as `double`. This requires padding at the end.

Answer (score 0):

On which platform you are running ? on my ubuntu machine it is giving me output 20 only !! 
sizeof unsigned int is 4 and double is 8 and thats why the output is 20 **on my machine**!! 
This varies from hardware to hardware !!